# Webrequest with NoAuth

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

I am creating a WebRequest to connect to a system at the moment and I am getting rejected on authorisation within Visual Studio. If I use the same credentials through Postman with NoAuth set it connects. How do I set the programmed version to have NoAuth for its credentials?

```
private HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = null;

            if (Reference != null && Password != null)
            {
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"{Host}/{Path}");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/xml";
                request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);

#if DEBUG   //Required for the localproxy
                IWebProxy webProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
                webProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                request.Proxy = webProxy;
#endif

                var body = $"v={Version}&ref={Reference}&password={Password}";
                var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;

                using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
            }

            return request;
        }
```

Comment: what error(Exact) are you getting?

Comment: I will dig the actual error out but it authorisation. so thinking about it I may actually be connecting. I will get back with more detail.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "Postman" do when you select "No Auth"? It does not send the "Authorization" parameter in request. If you are sending "Authorization" parameter in your request header simply remove it.

Comment: Would that be something like webRequest.Headers.Remove("Authorization");

Comment: You should try with "webRequest.Headers.Remove(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization)"

Comment: Thanks @user2485318